# Getting XML attribute based on another attribute in VBScript

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

I have the following XML that has been return from a SOAP API:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
<result>
<field name="accountnumber" value="100035" />
<field name="occupantcode" value="11" />
<field name="otherfield" value"do not care about this one" />
</result>
</results>
```

I am trying to load the account number into a variable called `AcctNum`, and the other one into `OccCode` using VBScript.  I am very new to XPath queries. I am trying something like this:

```vb
Set ANumNode = xmlResponse.SelectNodes("//results/result/field[@accountnumber]")
For Each objSite In ANumNode
  AcctNum = objSite.SelectSingleNode("accountnumber").Text
Next
```

but of course that is blowing up spectacularly.  There are actually about 20 field nodes in the response, of which I am only concerned with about 4 of them. I cannot change the format of the XML being outputted.

Comment: I can only offer you a partial answer, since my VB Script is more than rusty.  To get the account number the xpath used would (could) be "//field[@name='accountnumber']" and correspondingly "//field[@name='occupantcode']" which would return the nodes accordingly, from which you should be able to extract the text values.  Anything beyond that would be me guessing.  Hope it helps.

Comment: "Blowing up spectacularly" is a little unspecific. What *exactly* doesn't work as expected? What result did you expect? What result did you actually get? Did you receive an error? What does it say?

Comment: "Blowing up spectacularly" in this case is returning no results after trying multiple time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning XPath queries and instead built my own parser since the structure was going to be static:

```vb
Function retrieveValue(XMLblock, fieldname)
  start = 1
  '***Find field
  start = InStr(start, XMLBlock, "" & fieldname & "")
  '***Find value tag
  start = InStr(start, XMLBlock, "value")
  '***Find end quote for value
  endquote = InStr(start+7, XMLBlock, """")
  retrieveValue = Mid(XMLBlock, start+7, endquote-start-7)
End Function
```

Not the most elegant code, but it works so that I can continue on with my project. Thank you everyone for your assistance.

Comment: This isn't just "not the most elegant code". It's arguably the worst possible approach you could've taken.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your XML is not well-formed.
2. You need to understand the diffs between nodes and attributes

Use the docs ([start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742.aspx)) to work thru this sample code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim oFS    : Set oFS  = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
Dim sFSpec : sFSpec   = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName(".\43459134.xml")
Dim oXml   : Set oXml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")

oXml.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
oXml.async = False
oXml.load sFSpec

If 0 = oXml.parseError.errorCode Then
   WScript.Echo "loaded:", sFSpec
   WScript.Echo "root:", oXml.documentElement.tagName

   Dim sXPath, ndlResults, ndResult

   sXPath = "/results/result"
   Set ndlResults = oXml.selectNodes(sXPath)
   If 0 = ndlResults.length Then
      WScript.Echo "no '" & sXPath & "' found"
   Else
      WScript.Echo "found", ndlResults.length, "node(s) for '" & sXPath & "'"
      For Each ndResult In ndlResults
         WScript.Echo "ndResult.tagName:", ndResult.tagName
         Dim AcctNum : AcctNum = ndResult.selectSingleNode("field[@name=""accountnumber""]").getAttribute("value")
         Dim OccCod  : OccCod  = ndResult.selectSingleNode("field[@name=""occupantcode""]").getAttribute("value")
         WScript.Echo AcctNum, OccCod
      Next
   End If
Else
   WScript.Echo "errorCode:", oXml.parseError.errorCode
   WScript.Echo oXml.parseError.reason
End If
```

Output:

```
cscript 43459134.vbs
loaded: E:\work\proj\soa\tmp\43459134.xml
root: results
found 1 node(s) for '/results/result'
ndResult.tagName: result
100035 11
```

---

**Update wrt comments:**

The script 'works' for the (corrected) .xml you posted; if `/results/result` is located further down the tree, try `/REALDOCROOT/pi/pa/pi/results/result` or the less specific `//results/result`. Or else: post the real input.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get "no /result/results found".  That was after taking the live response saving it to a file, and reading it back in.